# load audios from django server

Tags: django, vue.js, audio, static

Here is my problem: I stored my audio files on my django server, and can successfully retrieve them on my vue application. However I only retrieve the 'url' ("/files/audios/2021/05/09/audio22.wav") of the audios and I do not know how to play them in my vue application. I tried integrating them as the source in an audio tag but it did not work.

Here is my **audiosView.py** :

```
class AudiosView(APIView):

def get(self, request):
    all_audios = Audio.objects.all().order_by("timestamp")
    ser = AudioSerializer(all_audios, many = True)
    return JsonResponse(ser.data, safe = False)

def post(self, request):
    ser = AudioSerializer(data = request.data)
    if ser.is_valid():
        ser.save()
        return JsonResponse(ser.data)
    return JsonResponse(ser.errors, status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Here is my **serializers.py**:

```
class AudioSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Audio
        fields = ("user", "rooms","audiofile","timestamp")
```

**Urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = [
path("audios/", AudiosView.as_view()),
path("audios/<slug:pk>", AudioView.as_view()),]
```

**models.py**

```
class Audio(models.Model):
  id = models.SlugField(max_length = 6, primary_key = True, unique = True)
  user = models.TextField( blank = True ,help_text="user who sent the audio")
  rooms = models.TextField( blank = True ,help_text="room where the audio was sent")
  audiofile = models.FileField(upload_to="audios/%Y/%m/%d")                    
  timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
  def __str__(self):
      return f"{self.id} ({self.user})"
```